# Inequality to have the Taylor expansion of the power 1/4

Tags: analysis, inequality, power-series, taylor-expansion, binomial-coefficients

Let be $j>2$ and $\mu<1/2$.
Consider the sum
$$ \sum_{h\ge j-1 }(-1)^h (2\mu)^h \binom{1/4}{h}$$
So, this sum is a negative quantity in view of the fact that $\binom{1/4}{h}=\frac{(-1)^{h+1}(4h-5)!!}{4^h h!}$. I have the following inequality (of positive quantities)
\begin{align*}
-\sum_{h\ge j-1 }(-1)^h (2\mu)^h \binom{1/4}{h}<&-(2\mu)^{j-1}\sum_{h\ge j-1}(-1)^h (2\mu)^{h-j+1}\binom{1/4}{h}\\
=&-(2\mu)^{j-1}\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^{k+j-1} (2\mu)^{k}\binom{1/4}{k+j-1}\\
<&(2\mu)^{j-1}\bigg[1-\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{(2\mu)^k(4k-5)!!}{k!4^k}\bigg]\\
=&(2\mu)^{j-1}\cdot(1-2\mu)^{1/4}
\end{align*}
where in the first inequality I just take out $(2\mu)^{j-1}$; in the second, I renamed the indicies; the third inequality is the one I can't have; the last is just the power expansion of $(1-2\mu)^{1/4}$. Can somebody help me with the third one?